# Como passar senha no run do docker

Tags: docker

Tenho no meu docker file um comando que eu faço clone usando git, estou usando o:
`ENV USUÁRIO \ SENHA`

Aí no comando (**dentro do dockerfile**) eu estou chamando essas ENV:

`RUN git clone git clone https://$USUARIO_BITBUCKET:$SENHA_BITBUCKET@bitbucket.org/.../...`

só que pra mim isso fica redundante, já que quero passar essa senha e login no run da imagem do tipo:

`docker run -e USUARIO=123 -e SENHA=123 IMAGEM COMANDO`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da forma como você fez, você precisa a todo momento modificar o Dockerfile para alterar o valor das variáveis USUARIO e SENHA. Também precisa reconstruir a imagem com **docker build -t  .**.

Obviamente, não é muito prático e também não é muito viável caso você queira distribuir essa sua imagem via o Docker Hub de forma que o usuário só precise informar a senha dele através do comando **docker run -e**.

Antes, lembre-se que as variáveis passadas através da opção **-e** ou do comando **ENV** no Dockerfile viram variáveis de ambiente no shell. Então, você pode ter um arquivo de script, por exemplo, **run.sh**. Ele pode ser mais ou menos assim:

```
#!/bin/bash
git clone git clone https://"$USUARIO_BITBUCKET":"$SENHA_BITBUCKET"@bitbucket.org/.../...
```

No seu Dockerfile, o qual você vai usar para criar sua imagem, modifique para algo assim:

```
FROM ubuntu
ADD run.sh run.sh
RUN chmod +x run.sh
CMD ./run.sh
```

Quando você executar esse container com o comando abaixo, ele vai usar as variáveis de ambiente passadas no comando **run**.

```
docker run --name teste -ti -e USUARIO_BITBUCKET=123 -e SENHA_BITBUCKET=123 nomeimagem
```